# Rearrange a 5D tensor using einops

Tags: python, pytorch

I am analyzing the implementation of the [**ViViT: A Video Vision Transformer**](https://github.com/rishikksh20/ViViT-pytorch/blob/a9879c9c0de677d33573fb4eb6bf76a638614974/vivit.py#L40). The input tensor of this model has the sahpe of (batch size, num frames, channels=3, H, W). When it comes to [patch embedding](https://github.com/rishikksh20/ViViT-pytorch/blob/a9879c9c0de677d33573fb4eb6bf76a638614974/vivit.py#L40), it uses the `Rearrange`  that is imported from `from einops.layers.torch import Rearrange` as follows:

```
  self.to_patch_embedding = nn.Sequential(
            Rearrange('b t c (h p1) (w p2) -> b t (h w) (p1 p2 c)', p1 = patch_size, p2 = patch_size),
            nn.Linear(patch_dim, dim),
        )
```

My question is that what will be happened to the input tensor [b, t,c,h,w] by the `Rearrange` function. This is because although I read the paper but it still is ambiguous for me?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Splitting each image into patches and ravel each image patch (in channels last format). Easier to see without batch and frames dimension `a = np.arange(3*4*6).reshape(3,4,6); print(a); einops.rearrange(a, 'c (h p1) (w p2) -> (h w) (p1 p2 c)', p1=2, p2=2)`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is an input tensor of shape `(32, 10, 3, 32, 32)` representing `(batchsize, num frames, channels, height, width)`.

`b t c (h p1) (w p2)` with `p1=2` and `p2=2` decomposes the tensor to `(32, 10, 3, (16, 2), (16, 2))`, as you can see, einops automatically infers that `h=16` and `w=16`

`b t (h w) (p1 p2 c)` composes the decomposed the tensor to `(32, 10, 16*16=256, 2*2*3=12)`

Your comment below about the decomposed tensor having 256 patches is indeed correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but one question raised for me. Because in the decomposed tensor we have (h, p1)=(16,2) and (w, p2)=(16,2). So, I think for composing the decomposed tensor when it comes to (h w), we would have 16*16 instead of 32*32. Can you please explain that.

Comment: h and w do not change, they are 32 and 32!